# Angular4で表示ページのurlを取得したい

Tags: angular4

Angular4でTypescriptで自身のURLを取得する方法はありますでしょうか？

以下のあたりを探っているのですが、

route: ActivatedRoute
location: Location

以下のようなすべてのURLを取得する方法がわかりませんでした…
http://xxxxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.location.href で取得できます。

Comment: hiroさま　本当にお恥ずかしいです。なんで、window.location.hrefを試していないのか…無事取得できました！